# Passing Server Side loop variable to Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assign Vb.net loop variable values to javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666402/assign-vb-net-loop-variable-values-to-javascript-array)

I am trying to assign Server Side Loop Variable to Client side array but its giving error.My code of server side and client side is bellow.

```
 <%  Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select STA_NAME, GPS_ONE from GPS", con)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim I As Long
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "GPS")
        For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
            I = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
            Dim GPS As String = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE")
            Dim STATION As String = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("STA_NAME")
        Next I


        con.Close()%>
```

Now i am trying to Pass

Dim GPS As String = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE")
  Dim STATION As String = ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("STA_NAME")

to Client side javascript

```
var GPS_A = '<%=GPS %>'
var GPS = new array();
[
new google.maps.LatLng(GPS_A)
];
```

But i am getting Compilation error at line

```
   var GPS_A = '<%=GPS %>'
```

Error is "GPS is not declared"

Please tell me what exactly i am missing and how can i do it