# Assign Vb.net loop variable values to javascript Array

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place Server side Variable in javascript loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667836/place-server-side-variable-in-javascript-loop)

I have Some Server side vb.net code getting Data from DB.Server side code is bellow

```
  Dim mgps As New Text.StringBuilder
    Public ReadOnly Property GPS() As String
        Get
            Return mgps.ToString
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection
        con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml; User ID=sml; Password=sml; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select STA_NAME, GPS_ONE from GPS", con)

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim I As Long
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "GPS")

        For I = 0 To ds.Tables("GPS").Rows.Count - 1
            mgps.AppendLine(ds.Tables("GPS").Rows(I).Item("GPS_ONE"))
        Next I

    End Sub
```

And here is Client side JS code where i want to use server side loop data

```
 var GPS1 = '<%=GPS %>';      
   var GPS = new Array();
   GPS = [
   new google.maps.LatLng(GPS1)
    ];
for(i=0; i<GPS.length; i++)
    {

          var image = 'ico/no.png';
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var ContentString = 'SML';
          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
          { 
           position: GPS[i],
           map: map,
           draggable:true,
           icon:image,
           title: "Adeel" + (i+1)
           });
```

But through this code my map is not loading.Please tell me how can i use the server side loop values into JS array to assign LatLang to markers